# What exactly is a screen reader and what should I do with my site?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

Sorry if this is a too naive question, but what exactly is a screen reader?  How should I consider them when designing a web page (html document)?

Doing a google search doesn't help much... and wikipedia's entry is too general.

Is there anything I should be adding into my html markup to deal with screen readers in particular?

Comment: A better starting point is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA

Comment: I've seen that ARIA before but I never really knew what they were used for.  Visited the link, gosh, that's a lot to take in... this subject is so large.

Comment: Sure is! Begin with Landmark roles and adding descriptive text to your visual elements. Use proper tags for abbreviations, title, time, acronyms, etc with the title attribute along the way. You might get better search engine traffic to boot!

Comment: You should consider **accessibility** as a whole, not just the (very) particular case of SR. A SR is an assistive technology used by blind people and some partially sighted people, with a Braille display and/or a speech synthesis. There are many other assistive technologies and there many other disabilities. Otherwise WCAG 2.0 is the W3C standard as stated by Patrick Hofman. ARIA is more specialised for, well, Rich Internet Applications (RIA). If your site isn't an app and is as simple as not having JS widgets like accordion, modals, etc and has semantics HTML, ARIA is nice but not necessary.

Comment: OP, please reread all of the answers provided, they all had errors, issues or inaccuracies. I edited them  to eliminate them for the most part. I stand behind Felipe's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update and edits.  I'm not sure which answer to accept for this question, so please feel free to accept by your own volition.  You certainly are in a position to know more about this than I do.

Answer (score 2):

Screen readers are typically used to make the computers accessible to users with visual disabilities, e.g. If you are blind you won't be able to see a website but with software you can have it "read" to you.

The most common screen reader I know of is the [JAWS screen reader](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/Jaws).

JAWS is short forL **J** ob **A** ccess **W** ith **S** peech (hence the name) and is a common tool used when trying to ensure your website or Web application is accessible. E.g. Creating sites for the U.S. Government require ensuring your content is accessible according to the Section 508 of the Rehabilitation Act: http://www.section508.gov/

All of the info you might need is on that site but a few of the quick tips would be:

- add informative descriptions to images with `alt` attributes
- use `<TH>` tags to properly define table headers and use the `scope` attribute
- ensure that your site/app still renders in a readable manner when the CSS is disabled

Answer (score 2):

A screen reader is software that "reads" a document (in your case, a webpage) and outputs it in a way that people with visual disabilities (e.g. blindness) can easily consume.

A screen reader can only understand text (and some formatting). Here are things you can (and should) do to improve accessibility for blind or almost-blind people:

- Use the `<strong>` and `<em>` tags rather than non-descriptive `<b>` or `<i>`. If it's being read aloud by the computer, it can put emphasis on those words.
- Always include the `alt` attribute on images. You can even leave it blank (also known as *null* - `alt=""`); this signifies that the image is not essential/decorative. Otherwise, put a text description of the image.
- The `title` attribute is generally ignored by accessibility software. In effect, only people that can use computer mouse can ever read it, so avoid it.
- Turn of CSS and look at your page. If it doesn't make sense, you should reconsider the layout.
- ARIA roles (via the `role` attribute) are helpful. For example, if you make a link look like a button, assistive technology provides different interactions. So by setting the `role` correctly, people using assistive technology can use that element as you intended. In that case you set `role="button"`
- Use tags with semantic meaning (like `section`, `article`, `nav`, `aside`, `header`, as well as the more common `h1...6` tags) rather than `div`s and `span`s that you style with CSS. This lets software make an outline of your page and a blind person can jump straight to the main content just like you can scan it with your eyes.
- Related to the last one; make it a point to use lesser-known tags like `time` and `abbr` and `address` rather than yet another CSS class.

And that's just for screen readers. Not even considering deaf people -- look into captions for your videos and audio (with the new HTML5 `<audio>` and `<video>` tags).

Please be aware that I am not an expert on accessibility (and I'm not blind either, so I don't speak from experience). The [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) has standards on accessibility that are probably more advisable than mine (and [a list of quick tips](http://www.w3.org/WAI/quicktips/) as well).

Comment: So basically, I should design my html in such a manner that maybe some text-only browsers might visit it?

Comment: @kerafill: That's a good way to think of it. Put as much content and meaning into words rather than pictures as you can. Better yet, download a screen reader like JAWS, turn off your screen, and try it out.

Comment: And I'd suggest (after you've done with your HTML and you believe it's accessible) to ask a really blind person to test it. You can do this, for example, by putting a #a11y (accessibility) hashtag in Twitter if you don't know anyone blind personally. A lot of people would be glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is two folded:

1. A screen reader is a piece of software that reads the screen and converts that to something people with visual disabilities can consume, like audio or Braille. In terms of the web, it reads the DOM, versus the actual screen.
2. What you have to do can be quite simple: make your application easy to understand for screen readers. You do this for example by providing `alt` with an image. There is a standard for working with screen readers at the W3C called [WCAG](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/). What you really need to do primarily depends on your audience. If it is unlikely to have people with such disabilities on your site, you probably have to do none to less work for it.

Comment: I'm fine, thank you.  It's a really big issue to have to handle for screen readers.  I've already installed JAWS (demo) and see where it goes from there.  So far, I'm just adding attributes as @scunliffe has suggested.

Comment: and @rvighne suggestions too.